# IAM User Secretskeys aren't getting create

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

i've express backend where i want to store the image files directly to the cloud instead of any local drive so i decided to use the aws.
it's my first time i'm ineracting with  any `aws service`

I've setup the`IAM policy for the user for my S3 bucket`
i've even attachted that policy to that user
but the thing when i clicked to create the user then it did create the user,but the thing is it's not showing the or creating the access keys or secret access keys which i'll be using in my express api.

I tried and read the docs that doesn't seems to solve my problem.

so the question is there any way that i've to create my keys manually ?

Comment: See [Managing access keys for IAM users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html). That said, using IAM user credentials for an application is not the best option. Use IAM Roles if the app runs in AWS and IAM Roles Anywhere if not.